# I need any sample of using ogr2ogr on Android

Tags: android, gdal

I want to use this command

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON"
```

to convert .TAB file to json 
but I want to do this in Android so I want to build this library for android 
I found this link 
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid
but I am wondering if there is any existing built library or any sample ?

I read the .DAT file using 
nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib but I need to read .MAP file also, How can I do that ?

Comment: Can I ask you if you considered my answer? Or could you revise the question?

Answer (score 1):

I have just done the build for Android (arm/x86) and the guide that you are pointing to is accurate.

I did a fair amount of searching and did not find pre-compiled libraries. It would be awesome if it could be included in cpp-to-java projects like https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets

Regarding filetypes: I have not seen examples of using .DAT or .MAP files in an Android project. You would normally look for static (.a) or dynamic (.so) libraries, or JAR/AAR java/android libraries.

Note that for a native library to work it needs to be compiled for the specific architecture that you are targeting with the app - e.g. armeabi-v7a or x86. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html